# how to fix my code as its showing NZEC error

Tags: python-3.x

```
from math import pow
s=pow(10,9)+7
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n=input().strip()
    n=int(n)-1
    k=pow(2,n)*10
    print(int(k%s))
```

can you please tell where my code has been wrong
its showing NZEC

Answer (score 0):

i dont know wt u r trying to ask exactly without the problem
as far as i can understand
try this:

```
from math import pow
s=pow(10,9)+7
aa=int(input());
bb=list(map(float,input().split()))
for n in bb:
    n=int(n)-1
    k=pow(2,n)*10
    print(int(k%s))
```